# Possible strange output of javascript forEach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, iteration

How does this output make any sense? Maybe I am thinking about it wrong but it seems fairly descriptive in what it's supposed to be dong

```
var dataset = [1, 2, 3];

dataset.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    //          (index, how many to remove)
    array.splice(0, 0);
});

returns [1,2,3] as expected
```

---

```
dataset.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    array.splice(0, 3);
});

returns [] as expected
```

---

```
dataset.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
   array.splice(0, 1);
});

returns [3]
```

---

```
dataset.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    array.splice(0, 2);
});

returns [3]
```

This has got me questioning my understanding of everything lol. I had a more complex requirement where an array of objects may have property "element.archived"

```
var dataset = [Object, Object, Object]

dataset.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
   if (element.archived) array.splice(index, 1);
});
```

I am trying to iterate over the array, and remove all objects that have this property value of true.

Comment: methinks you just use wrong instrument for filtering. seems you need simple [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Why are you doing `array.splice` *inside* the `forEach`?  Do you *really* need to run `splice` on the array 3 times?

Comment: @RocketHazmat, _exactly_ what my question was going to be. OP you seem to have a misunderstanding of [how `splice` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: I thought splice was to remove a particular element or insert at a particular element, basically. Coming from python... yes.. yes I did want to run splice on that array. I wanted to splice is so hard.

Comment: you _resolved_ method - ugly :-) callback in filter function should return _boolean_, so you not need `If` just `return !obj.archived` is enough

Comment: `splice` modifies indices, `forEach` starts from `0` and counts up. When it reaches a non-defined index it stops. Because the length changed, the non-defined index is earlier. Therefore `forEach` is invoked less than _initial length_ times

Comment: @JasonMacAnLighiche: Do *not* edit your solution into the question.  The question should remain a *question*.  What you should do is *accept* the correct answer.

Comment: What if my fix is more specific to the answer given? I know sometimes people appreciate finding an answer 6 months down the line. Just curious.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to remove objects from an array that has `archived: true`. Here's a couple of ways to do this:

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) which returns a *new* filtered array:

```
var arr = dataset.filter(function (el) {
  return el.archived !== true;
});
```

Or you can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove elements as you iterate over them:

```
for (var i = dataset.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (dataset[i].archived === true) dataset.splice(i, 1);
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kwr7w18c/)

Comment: seems sample with _splice_ wrong - when we remove item we should not increment `i` variable

Comment: Doh. Thanks for the headsup.

Comment: @Andy instead of decrementing `i` for each match or "not incrementing" it, it is actually easier to loop downwards instead as these indices won't be changed `var i = dataset.length; while (i-- > 0) {...}`

Comment: @PaulS., thanks. Sometimes you repeat code enough times it becomes habit and never think there might be a better way of writing it until someone points it out